# Spark Broadcasting Alternatives

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Our application uses a long-running spark context(just like spark RPEL) to enable users perform tasks  online. We use spark broadcasts heavily to process dimensional data. As in common practice, we broadcast the dimension tables and use dataframe APIs to join the fact table with the other dimension tables. One of the dimension tables is quite big and has about 100k records and 15MB of size in-memory(kyro serialized is just few MBs lesser).

We see that every spark JOB on the de-normalized dataframe is causing all the dimensions to be broadcasted over and over again. The bigger table takes ~7 secs every time it is broadcasted. We are trying to find a way to have the dimension tables broadcasted only once per context life span. We tried both sqlcontext and sparkcontext broadcasting.

Are there any other alternatives to spark broadcasting? Or is there a way to reduce the memory footprint of the dataframe(compression/serialization etc. - post-kyro is still 15MB :( ) ?

Comment: When are the tables available? are they created at the beginning of the program and sent to all workers for the duration of the program?

Comment: These are hive tables under the covers and the dimension tables are broadcasted during the start of the program and user continues to wrangle data after the initial load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we were able to  find a stopgap solution until spark support pinning of RDDs or preferably RDDs in a later version. This is apparently not addressed even in v2.1.0.

The solution relies on RDD mapPartitions, below is a brief summary of the approach

- Collect the dimension table records as map of key-value pairs and broadcast using spark context. You can possibly use RDD.keyBy
- Map fact rows using RDD mapPartitions method. 
  For each fact row mapParitions

  - collect the dimension ids in the fact row and lookup the dimension records
  - yields a new fact row by denormalizing the dimension ids in the fact 
    table

Answer (score 0):

Possible Alternative

We use Iginite spark integration to load large amount of data at start of job and keep on mutating as needed.

In embedded mode you can start ignite at boot of Spark context and kill in the end.

You can read more about it here.

https://ignite.apache.org/features/igniterdd.html

Comment: Can you please review your response? Doesn't seem to answer my question.